# Reduced Density Matrix Fermions

Tags: fermions, density-operator, many-body

Suppose we've got a fermionic state
$$
\rho=\bigotimes_{i=1}^N|v_i\rangle\langle v_i|
$$
where $|v_i\rangle=\left(\sqrt{d_i}c^\dagger(\psi_i)+\sqrt{1-d_i}c^\dagger(\eta_i)\right)|0\rangle_i$. The vectors $\psi_i\in\Lambda$ and $\eta_i\in\Lambda^\perp$ are orthonormal. The question is now how do I obtain the partial trace
$$
\rho_\Lambda=\operatorname{tr}_{\Lambda^\perp}\rho.
$$
This question is motivated by the computation on the first two page of the paper of [Klich 2003](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0406068.pdf).